# How to change Vuetify Text fields text input color

Tags: textfield, vuetify.js

How to change Vuetify `v-text-fields` input text color. I tried many ways but none of them is worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJvJ.png)

I tried to change the "Hello" text to red. It is not working.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example to help you

Comment: I added a picture.

Answer (score 6):

There are few ways to do this.

One convenient way is to set a class on the `v-text-field`, then using specificity set the `color` of the `input`.

Note that you need to use the `!important` flag when not editing the Vuetify theme directly.

In the template,

```html
    <v-text-field class="text-green"></v-text-field>
```

In the CSS (e.g. style tag),

```css
    .text-green input {
      color: green !important;
    }
```

*Live Snippet*:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    name: 'John'
  })
})
```

```css
.text-green input{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-text-field class="text-green" v-model="name"></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but the text does not change colour to red.

Comment: @Xuan I have updated the answer as I forgot about using `!important` when using the default theme.

Comment: Is the :value="computedText" necessary for this to work? I got an error Property or method "computedText" is not defined in the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Not at all. It's not related. I just placed that there to simulate that some generated text will be displayed.

Comment: Then it will not work. I tried this way of doing a thing but It was not worked for me. I tried again but it is still not working.

Comment: @Xuan I have removed that portion of the post as it was distracting and not essential

Comment: It is so weird that it does not work. It seems to have no error when I inspect the element the color: red!important; does not show. It does not apply I think.

Comment: @Xuan [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/seantunwin/pen/xoObyB) which a fork of the Solo style example on the [Vueitify Text Field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#solo-style) page

Comment: @Xuan Added live snippet example to answer as well

Comment: Ohhhh my god, I am so stupid. I added scoped to my style so that I cannot make my style global that is why I cannot see my style when I tried to add the color: red !important; I knew it is weird. I am so dumb.

Comment: @Xuan We've all been there. No worries. Glad you sorted it out. :-)

Answer (score 5):

if you want to change color to white just add props `dark` to v-text-input
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is exporting the themes colors as css variables (custom properties). Code below

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
  },
})
```

and then in the scss using the following code:

```
 .v-text-field {
input {
  color: var(--v-primary-base);
}
```

}

Comment: if you use scoped css you would have to go for the deep selector solution (e.g.  ::v-deep)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<v-text-field class="text-input-blue"/>
```

In combination with CSS:

```
.text-input-blue .v-text-field__slot input {
   color: #00f !important;
}
```

One of the downsides of Javascript frameworks is that the CSS is often hard to customize.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using v-custom the below scss override will work for you:

```
<div class="input-text-wrapper">
    <v-text-field class="input-text"/>
</div>
```

Style:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">

    .input-text {
        ::v-deep {
            .v-text-field {
                input {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file related to CSS styles in the Styles section and name it Override. In that file, you can make any desired changes you need. Put the following code in that file, you can change the color of the border:

```
.v-text-field {
    input {
      color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.33);
    }
  }
```